# Trouble with writing text to a .ini file

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

I am working on a small game project in the Unity 3D engine. I am trying to write a class that will allow a settings menu to write the recorded settings to an .ini file. However, I can't seem to get myto write to the file. I think I wrote the class correctly to do it based upon the MSDN article on the subject. Here is my class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

//Used to allow other files to access the script by name
namespace INI

{
public class iniFile {
    public string path;

    string winDir=System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");

    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string value, string filePath);
    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);

    /// INIFile Constructor.
    public iniFile(string INIPath) {
        path = INIPath;
    }
    /// Write Data to the INI File
    public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value) {
        long success = WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
        Debug.Log (Section);
        Debug.Log (Key);
        Debug.Log (Value);
        Debug.Log (path);
        Debug.Log (success);
        return;
    }

    /// Read Data Value From the Ini File
    public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key) {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section,  Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
        return temp.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my call for this class:

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width * guiGameplayApplyButtonPlaceX, Screen.height *    guiGameplayApplyButtonPlaceY, Screen.width * guiGameplayApplyButtonSizeX, Screen.height *     guiGameplayApplyButtonSizeY), "Apply")) {
        ini.IniWriteValue("Gameplay","Difficulty","Test");
        print ("Apply");
    }
```

I created the instance of the class like this:

```
iniFile ini = new iniFile(@"..\settings\settingsTest.ini");
```

Comment: What did or didn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not the exact answer to your question, but what for you want to create file with settings? Wouldn't be much easier, to use Unity3d built-in feature for saving game preferences, which also works cross-platform?

If you want to give it a try, read about [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Comment: Sorry for getting back to your so late, I thought that it would email me when someone posted a comment. Evidently, it does not. I really don't want to do it with the PlayerPrefs because it saves it to the registry. I want to do it with .ini files because it is the format that works best for me.